# suspending negative values during object definition (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9, python-class

Since Im refreshing my python skills at the moment I stumbled across the problem of suspending (for example negative attribute values) during object definition.

```
class Motorcycle:
    def __init__(self,make,displacement):
        self.make=make            
        self.displacement=displacement
```

it would make sense to suspend negative values for the displacement attribute(and ask as long for another value until a positive value is entered), but I can't find a way to do that during object definition.

Comment: What do you mean by "suspending"?  Do you mean "rejecting"  Do you want to raise an exception?  Or do you just want to force negative values to zero?

Comment: Have you tried using an `if` statement? What went wrong?

Comment: "and ask as long for another value until a positive value is entered" - asking for user input doesn't sound like the constructor's job.

Comment: How many different versions of Python are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can raise an exception in case you are getting an negative value. You should also add info in the docstring indicating you want positive values for displacement:

```py
class Motorcycle:
    def __init__(self, make, displacement):
        if displayment < 0:
            raise ValueError('Value for displacement must be non-negative')

        self.make=make            
        self.displacement=displacement
```

Comment: thank you very much it worked! I tried this before but it seems like I made a mistake. Now it works.